# iPhone - dataWithContentsOfURL: does not work for some URLs

Tags: iphone, nsdata

I am using NSData to get content from a URL (RSS feed) and then parse it. While most of the URLs are loaded fine, some of them don't return any data.

These URLs open on the web so I know they are valid, but they just don't return any NSData. One such URL - `feed://jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/rss/rovers.xml`

Here's how I am using it (the NSURL object is formed properly)

```
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[myUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not really answering your question, try using:

dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:

to get the error of the call.  Just pass it a pointer to an error variable and read from it afterwards.

Comment: The error code's not very helpful. This is what it shows - NSCocoaErrorDomain

Comment: NSCocoaErrorDomain code 256 is "NSFileReadUnknownError, Read error, reason unknown". Try something like curl to see what's actually coming back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `NSURLConnection` so you have some delegate methods to watch what's happening in debugger. check out the URL Loading System docs if you haven't.